# Connect to remote Azure Linux machine through ssh Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, azure, visual-studio-code, ssh

I want to connect to an Azure machine on which is installed an Ubuntu distribution.

I can connect or through ssh or, by installing some other software, by using X2Go.
However, I don't need the UI and if it's possible I would like to use Visual Studio Code.
On this last I've installed the ssh component and I've already used it to connect to other machines.

Unfortunately I'm not able to connect to the Azure machine by using VS Code.
The ssh connection works, I tested it by connecting through the terminal.

The connection string is in the following for:
`(user_name)@(machine_name).westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`

I'm not the system administrator and I don't know the public IP.

I think the problem is the ssh port, I read that the standard port for ssh is `22` while I have `53044`.

On VS Code I tried the following solution:

- connection string: `(user_name)@(machine_name).westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:53044`
- I added the connection info into the config file with this format:

```
Host Linux_Azure
    HostName (machine_name).westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    User (user_name)
    Port 53044
```

None of them work.

With the first solution VS Code tries to connect forever, failing with no error messages.

With the second solution VS Code gives back this error message: `Could not establish connection to "Linux_Azure": The connection timed out`.

I don't understand why it doesn't work, and I don't know how to solve it.

Do you have any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I deployed one Ubuntu VM and tried connecting to it via SSH in VS code and got connected successfully with Port 22 like below:-

```bash
ssh siliconuser@siliconlinuxvm123.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com -p 22
```

**Output:-**

[image]
[image]

When I tried connecting with port 53044, Even I got the same error code as yours like below:-

[image]

***By default Azure Linux VM uses Port 22 to SSH, You cannot change the default destination port as it is fixed for a particular protocol. Example For RDP - Port 3389 is used, For HTTP- Port 80 and for SSH- Port 22 is used.***

***When I try to allow SSH in the inbound rule on VM's Networking Page > Port 22 is selected by default and greyed out thus we cannot add other port as a destination range*** ***refer below:-***

[image]

Comment: I tried to use port 22 but it doesn't work. It gives me back the same errors that I said above. Then you connect by using the terminal inside the VS Code, that works also for me. However, I would like to connect through the `Remote - SSH` extension in order to use all the functionalities of VS Code.